# Resilience4J for Springboot - what is the use of registerHealthIndicator: true

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

In Resilience4J for spring boot what is the use of registerHealthIndicator: true ?

The document https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#health-endpoint says if we configure as below in application.yml we can see the status of circuit breakers in health endpoint.

```
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
```

When i try my actuator health endpoint - http://localhost:8080/actuator/health i see only one status : {"status":"UP"} . There are no details about circuit breaker in it.

Is there any config that i am missing for health endpoint ?

Note: I am able to see the circuit breaker details in other endpoints like
- http://localhost:8080/actuator/circuitbreakerevents
- http://localhost:8080/actuator/circuitbreakers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see detailed information in the `/health` endpoint you need to change the property `management.endpoint.health.show-details` configuration. It defines when to show full health details and by default its value is `never`. You need to actually configure it as `always` as follows:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details = always
```